# loop date insert x times php

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to put together some code in PHP so that after I add a date, the next x number dates are added.

Without going into specifics, the general idea is that after a customer has been visited, the visit date will be entered, this then triggers this code, to add the next x visit dates in (the visits will be every 6 months), but depending on the customer there may be 3, 4 or 5 visits, I have this set as a $value and am good with that and being able to calculate future dates.

What I dont know is how to loop the insert, so if

```
$value = 4, then
n1, initial date + 6 months
n2, initial date + (6*2) months
n3, initial date + (6*3) months
n4, initial date + (6*4) months - yes i know i could just add 6 months to n-1, but trying to keep it simple.
```

I have never worked with nth term approach in a loop and wondered if someone could a) point me in the direction of a related article, and b) give me an example.

Basically what I want to do is LOOP it x times ($value = x), and then in each loop be able to use 6 * x.

Thanks

Comment: _but depending on the customer there may be 3 or 5 visits, I have this set as a $value_ Except `$value = 4` which is not 3 or 5?

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < $value; ++$i)` not working for you?

Comment: So use a simple `for` loop, where is the actual problem with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the DateTime object and the DateInterval Object this can be done quite simply using a `for` loop.

```
$frequency = 6;    // could be 6 or 12 months, set elsewhere in your code

$visit_count = 5; //for this example
$initial_date = new DateTime($value["VisitDate"]);  // last visit date

$interval = new DateInterval("P$frequencyM");    // visit every $frequency  months

for ( $i=0; $i < $visit_count; $i++ ) {
    $visits[] = clone $initial_date->add($interval);
}
print_r($visits);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2023-01-01 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [1] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2023-07-01 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [2] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2024-01-01 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [3] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2024-07-01 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [4] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2025-01-01 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks that looks just the job, 2 quick questions, how would I amend that if the initial_date is actually a field, so $value["VisitDate"]; and also if the interval is also a variable, so $frequency, could I use 'P.'$freuency.'M'?

Comment: What format is `$value["VisitDate"];` in i.e. is it yyyy-mm-dd or dd/mm/yy

Comment: it is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Sorry one more, when inside the loop, how would i recall the loop date, so say within the {} if I wanted to insert that new date into another table, what function do I use within the loop.  I will use INSERT INTO ...tablename... (visit date) values (loopdate), etc.  - i know not that format, but hopefully gives you an idea of what i mean

Comment: Sorry i think i was unclear, when you wrote $interval = new DateInterval('P6M');  , the 6 can be either 6 or 12, i have this number set as $frequency, ie frequency (between visits in months), so how would I translate P6M, to P$frequencyM, thanks again

Comment: If you want to learn how to update a database I suggest you start by looking at [The PHP Manual, at the PDO database access extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and maybe [this tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) If you then get problems, ask another question more specifically about your issue

Comment: Ok, made a change for the `P6M` change